# Show that $\mathbb{E}(g(T-p)) < \mathbb{E}(g(S-p))$ for any convex function $g$ if $T$ and $S$ are estimators of $p$

Tags: point-estimation

The more detailed question.

[image: question]

I'm kinda having some trouble starting out with answering this question. My initial approach would be to $g(x)= x^2$ since that is a convex function and find the expected values of $(T-P)^2$ and $(S-P)^2$.

However I fear that that would be too specific since the question would like to prove for any convex function. Is there a way to prove this more generally?

Comment: Use the hint provided and note that the inequality is to be proven for the specific estimators $T$ and $S$,and for the specific distributional assumption on $X$ -the expected value here is a sum, not even an integral. There is no need to specify a functional form for $g$.

Comment: That's it? well for E(g(S-p)) I got (1-p)g(-p)+pg(1-p) and for E(g(T-p)) = (1-p)^2g(-2)+2p(1-p)g(0.5-p)+p^2g(1-p). I know p^2<p since 0<p<1 but how what do I do with the 2p(1-p)g(0.5-p) in E(g(T-p))

Comment: Sorry a type. *But what do I do with the 2p(1-p)g(0.5-p) in E(g(T-p)) in order to satisfy the inequality?

Comment: Write down the inequality you want to prove, with the expected values you worked out. Move things around. Take common factors. Simplify. Try to manipulate the remaining terms so that the fundamental inequality describing a convex function emerges.

Comment: Ah, I think that really helps. I guess I just needed an idea on where to go. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Note that in the comment at least you wrote $g(-2)$ instead of $g(-p)$.

Comment: Oh dear you're right. Anyway I attempted it and got it simplified to satisfy the convexity criteria. Thanks so much for your help. I only got to worry about one question left.

Comment: You might want to post the answer so that this question is closed, and is not left un-answered.

Comment: Oh right, I'll post it up as soon as I can, after I get some sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alecos Papadopoulos, I was able to answer the question. My answer is as follows. Apologies in advance. I keep having trouble trying to get my MathJax command to display properly.

[image: a busy cat]

Thus satisfying the convexity identity.